# Sqoop2 Hbase Import:Could not insert row with null value for row-key column

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, sqoop

I am trying to migrate the data from oracle to Hbase with sqoop job.It looks like that it has successfully exported but it throws an error while importing the same in Hbase.

Job1:

```
​ `​sqoop import --verbose --connect *** --username *** --password *** --table 'abc' --columns "MID,EID,RTIMESTAMP,VALUE,UTIMESTAMP" --split-by 'abc.ID' --hbase-table "HPVSQOOP" --column-family "cf1" --hbase-row-key MID,EID,RTIMESTAMP --num-mappers 4 --hbase-bulkload​
```

​where ID is the primary key in Oracle but I want my HBase row-key to be as MID_EID_RTIMESTAMP

​Map-Reduced failed by throwing an Error:
​

> ​INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1492489711789_0014_m_000003_2,
>   Status : FAILED Error: java.io.IOException: Could not insert row with
>   null value for row-key column: MID,EID,RTIMESTAMP at
>   org.apache.sqoop.hbase.ToStringPutTransformer.getPutCommand(ToStringPutTransformer.java:146)
>   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseBulkImportMapper.map(HBaseBulkImportMapper.java:83)

​
Another Job with --query is not working with Hbase import.
​
​Job2:

```
​sqoop import --verbose --connect *** --username *** --password **' --query "select MID,EID,VALUE,RTIMESTAMP,UTIMESTAMP,ID from database.abc where \$CONDITIONS" --split-by 'abc.ID' --hbase-table "HPVSQOOP" --column-family "cf1" --hbase-row-key "MID,EID,RTIMESTAMP" --num-mappers 4 --hbase-bulkload
```

​ended up throwing an error: 
​

> ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

If the column name is lowercase in your database, you should use lowercase names in the command line like this `--hbase-row-key "mid,eid..."`